# Using Hbase into Hive, possible?

Tags: hadoop, memory, hive, hbase, bigdata

I have data stored in Hive, I want access to them from Hbase getting fast perfomance. Is this possible? 
Is there another framework which can access to hive using memory? Just no Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is storage handler called

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler
```

through which you will be able to access hive data through Hbase.Create a table in HBase and map that table to a hive table using the below syntax. After that load the hive table and then access it from hbase.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(.......)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "......")
TBLPROPERTIED ("hbase.table.name" = "........");
```

Comment: There is Hive to Hbase, not Hbase to Hive. Indeed, TBLPROPERTIED links to hbase.table.

Comment: for that only i told first create a table in hbase then create the table in hive then load the hive table with data and then view it from hbase.... hope you got it

Comment: So, if I load data in new Hive table, linkking to HBase, HBase takes all data as well?

Comment: There is not a very clean solution; almost it is. Thanks.

Comment: Ok... You can accept or vote if you find useful or you are not able to get any better solution....